# PHP flexible(?) search on CSV file

Tags: php

struggling here with doing a search on an array, for example:

string1; string2; string3; 
string4; string5; string6;

If I use preg_match, I can search the array and it will return a result if the search pattern is exactly the same as an item in the array e.g. if the search term is “string1”. 
My question is, is there a way to return a positive result if the search string doesn’t have an exact match, e.g. if the search term is “my string” it would return all 6 as suggested results. 
Thanks!

Comment: why not run preg_match several times ? one time for each word and one time with all the search term ?

Answer (score 0):

You can explode this by `;`, loop and use `similar_text()` function to check how similar is keyword with each string and decide if you want it or not.

```
$percent = 0;
similar_text($keyword, $string, $percent);
if ($percent > 85) {
   // match
}
```

Comment: Good answer, that's allot more useful than the PCRE functions (preg_...) I've been looking in the wrong places for a solution! Thanks